# How can I read and process this kind of file

Tags: c, io

```
I 12 0

I 9 1

I 26 0

I 25 2

B 26

P 0

R 25

A
```

So, what I need to do is read a file containing these characters/numbers and whenever I encounter a letter, I call a function to process whatever comes after the letter (aka the numbers). 
For example:
 When reading "I" I have to call the function to `INSERT` a certain number in a certain level of a Skip List; or when reading B, I need to search for a specific number in the Skip List, etc.

Problem is I'm really bad at reading from a file, can you guys enlighten me?

Comment: You can have a look at the function strtok() to parse the input lines

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You won't get better by having someone just paste up the code of exactly how to do it.

Comment: Seriously, how can *you* be bad at reading from a file? If you *don't know* how to *do it using C*, then go to your favourite search engine, and type: "file IO with C" and read the first few tutorials. It's the only way you will learn...

Comment: Thank you Anand, using strtok() is a good idea, I will try it!

Comment: Also C is far from the best choice when it comes to parsing. I would avoid it unless it's explicitly stated as a requirement.

Comment: @KBart Yes. You are correct. I would prefer PERL script instead.

Comment: let me google that for you .....

Comment: Unfortunately it IS required to solve the problem using C, KBart. I didn't know it was far from the best choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with file operations in c,
i am just giving you hints,

```
FILE *pFilePtr; // file pointer(handle of file)

pFilePtr = fopen(argv[1],"r"); 

//define buffer to store data read line by line data
char buf[32]={0};

//Now you can run a while loop to read entire file
```

with fread() to get whole first line(until '\n')

```
while(!feof(pFilePtr))
```

{

```
if(NULL != fgets(buf,32,pFilePtr))

// perform string operation on buffer to extract letters and digits

// and according to that call functions you need
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will try to finish the program now.

Comment: One nit - don't use `feof` as your loop condition.  `feof` won't return true until *after* you've tried to read past the end of file, so your loop will execute one time too many.  Use the result of `fgets` as your loop condition instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *fptr;
    char mystring[20];
    int number;
    fptr = fopen("Input.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fptr , "%s %d", mystring, &number) !=  EOF) {
        printf("%s %d\n", mystring, number);

        if(strcmp(mystring, "I") == 0) { 
            printf("Implement the reqd function here\n");
        }
    }
}
```